# Xampp with Aws issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, dns

I am using an Aws EC2 with Ubuntu, I installed Xampp and it is working fine, the problem that I have it's that if I put this url:

[xellin.com](https://xellin.com)

It will open the Xampp dashboard... if you check this url too:

[http://xellin.com/akivoy/](https://xellin.com/akivoy)

You will see that there is a website, I wonder how can I do if I put xellin.com it diplays what it's in xellin.com/akivoy?

Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If xellin.com is your domain, you need to associate it with the elastic IP address of your EC2 instance. It is the only way in which DNS systems will know how route/propagate traffic to your instance.